# Non-Riemanian geometry such that $\frac{s}{D} \ne \pi$?

Tags: differential-geometry, geometry

In *euclidian geometry*, it's a basic fact of life that the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter defines $\pi$:
$$\frac{s}{D} = \pi, \tag{1}$$
where $\pi \approx 3.1415926$.  I always found this property a bit strange.

Also, in any curved *Riemann geometry*, the same is true for any sufficiently small circle relative to the local curvature, of diameter $$D \ll \frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}, \tag{2}$$ where $R$ is the scalar curvature evaluated at the middle of the circle.  If the circle is large, curvatures kicks in such that
$$\frac{s}{D} = f(D) \ne\pi. \tag{3}$$
Locally, a curved Riemannian geometry should reduces to euclidian geometry, so (1) is still true (for small circles).

For example, consider a 2D Riemann space of metric

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{1 + r^2 / a^2} \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d\varphi^2, \tag{4}$$

where $a$ is an arbitrary constant which has dimensions of a length.  A circle of "radius parameter" $b$ then has perimeter $s = 2 \pi b$ and diameter

$$D = 2 \int_0^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + r^2 / a^2}} \, dr = 2 a \, \ln{(b/a + \sqrt{1 + b^2 / a^2})}. \tag{5}$$

The ratio then gives the following.  I define $u = b / a$ for simplicity:

$$\frac{s}{D} = \Big( \frac{u}{\ln{(u + \sqrt{1 + u^2})}} \Big) \, \pi \equiv \frac{\sinh{(D / 2 a)}}{(D / 2 a)} \, \pi, \tag{6}$$
This reduces to $\pi$ when $b \ll a$ (small circle, relative to curvature),

Now, I wonder if it's possible to change the basic rules of "flat" euclidian geometry such that (1) is modified (I select the number 4 as an example.  It could be any other given constant instead of $\pi$):
$$\frac{s}{D} = 4,\tag{7}$$
for any *circle* ** (whatever its size).  Of course, such a geometry wouldn't be Riemannian, since usual curved geometries should reduce to euclidian geometry in a sufficiently small region.  So is it possible to define some strange **2D non-Riemannian geometries** such that (7) is true?  Or is there a way to prove that it's actually impossible, and that such geometries cannot be constructed?

** I defined a *circle* as a 2D figure for which all the points are at an equal distance to a given point not on the figure (the figure's *center*).  This obviously requires a *metric* to define a *distance* in the 2D space which contains the figure.  This may implies automatically a Riemann geometry, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible to construct such alternative geometries. An example is the [taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). But maybe math.SE would be a better fit for such a question since I do not see immediate physics connection here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry#Circles_and_disks

Comment: @G.Smith, hyperbolic geometries don't fit the question, since it's just a standard Riemannian geometry that reduces to Euclidian space for any small region.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t catch that you wanted this to hold for an arbitrarily small circle. I somehow missed the “non-Riemannian”!

Comment: Why the close vote?  Geometry, length and distance are all about physics.  I believe that this question belongs to physics, not just maths.

Comment: But then you could argue that nearly every math post belongs in physics, at some point you have to draw a line, and this is definitely arguably more math with no physics. I do support it being posted to mathematics instead.

Comment: @Triatticus, I don't agree.  Geometry IS physics!  Even Gauss stated this.

Comment: If you want a "2 dimensional" context for "length of curves" then Finsler geometries may interest you as a generalisation of Riemannian geometry. The wiki link above by AVS is an example of a non-Riemannian Finsler geometry on $\Bbb R^n$. The problem here is: What is the volume of a circle? Riemannian geometry has a canonical (even the constant is determined!) volume form, for Finsler geometry this is not clear to me (and a google search reveals there are many "canonical" volume forms, and it is not clear whether they are unique or only unique up to a constant).